# how do I write create method in the controller for a submission form that uses a join table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to create a form that allow called submits. I've got all the appropriate MVC created. I've then created a model called questions that works and am using active admin to allow admin users to add new questions to the form as they see fit. When I test submitting the form I get this error

```
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
    @submit = Submit.new(submit_params)
@submit.save
params[:submit][:question_ids].each do |question_id|
  @question = Question.find(question_id)
  @submit.questions << @question
end
```

Here's my submits controller:

```
class SubmitsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_submit, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

 def index
  @submits = Submit.all
 end

 def show
 end


 def new
  @submit = Submit.new
  @questions = Question.all
end


 def edit
 end


 def create
   @submit = Submit.new(submit_params)
   @submit.save
    params[:submit][:question_ids].each do |question_id|
     @question = Question.find(question_id)
     @submit.questions << @question
   end

   respond_to do |format|
     if @submit.save
         format.html { redirect_to @submit, notice: 'Application was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @submit }
      else
       format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @submit.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
 end


 def update
   respond_to do |format|
     if @submit.update(submit_params)
       format.html { redirect_to @submit, notice: 'Application was successfully updated.' }
       format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @submit }
     else
       format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @submit.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

 def destroy
   @submit.destroy
   respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to submits_url, notice: 'Submit was successfully destroyed.' }
     format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

Here's my Submit and Question model:

Submit:

```
class Submit < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :questions

  belongs_to :user
end
```

Question:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :submits
end
```

I'm sure it's some kind of syntax error in my controller but I don't know what. Still pretty new to using join tables. Any help/explanation would be very appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need this

```
params[:submit][:question_ids].each do |question_id|
  @question = Question.find(question_id)
  @submit.questions << @question
end
```

I don't see your submit params but if you add question ids to the permitted parameters then rails will build the entry in the join table on it's own.

```
def submit_params
  params.require(:submit).permit(:user_id, question_ids: [])
end
```

Comment: Thank you! that worked. Quick questions so I can understand why it worked. Why is the syntax question_ids: [] in the permitted params? If it's too long to answer it'd help to point me in the right direction.

Comment: Well that is what you're submitting as you're aware as you had `params[:submit][:question_ids]`.  The `[]` just tells strong parameters to accept an array.